# Flutter_facebook_connect : MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Tags: facebook, authentication, flutter

[Flutter_facebook_connect](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_connect#pub-pkg-tab-installing)

I updated my info.plist, and my app is registered on facebook developer with http://localhost:8080 as the OAuth redirect URL, but I got this MissingPluginException.

After looking it up, [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357053/flutter-test-missingpluginexception) suggested adding   `SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});`

This got rid of the the error but flutter_facebook_connect is still not working. Is there something I could be missing?

Comment: How is it not working?  Your question is difficult to answer without specifics.

Comment: So I'm pretty sure the flutterWebviewPlugin is what's causing the problem. Flutter_facebook_connect uses the web view Plugin to launch the url. I tried just extracting that bit and doing a flutterWebviewPlugin.launch("http://google.com"); and the app did not launch the web view at all.

Comment: Yeah flutterWebviewPlugin is throwing an unhandled exception and then directing me to platform_channel.dart and highlights this line:      throw new MissingPluginException("No implementation found for method $method on channel $name");

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Unhandled exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared\_preferences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687801/flutter-unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for)