# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

**[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)**

- I am using  **firebase_messaging** to handle push notification
- when my app going to the background and push notification arrives, that time **onBackgroundMessage** method call and this error occurred
- I have already tried many solutions which are related to this issue but still, I am facing this issue
- here is my **onBackgroundMessage** method code

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  print("myBackgroundMessageHandler: $message");
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    // Handle data message
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
    print("myBackgroundMessageHandler: $message");
    var emailMessageId = message['data']['message_id'];
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

- I am getting this error when getting SharedPreferences instance

Comment: i this you added SharedPreferences package while app was running and you did not give full restart to app. because of that you may face this error. so stop you app and again run you app.

Comment: my app is already running and then I put the App into the background

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Unhandled exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared\_preferences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687801/flutter-unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for)