# Flutter compilation error - Execution failed for task ':flutter_paystack:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter

```
e: C:\SRC_Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_paystack-1.0.2+1\android\src\main\kotlin\co\paystack\flutterpaystack\FlutterPaystackPlugin.kt: (33, 88): Unresolved reference: VERSION_NAME
e: C:\SRC_Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_paystack-1.0.2+1\android\src\main\kotlin\co\paystack\flutterpaystack\FlutterPaystackPlugin.kt: (37, 36): Unresolved reference: VERSION_CODE

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_paystack:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 23s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Thank you Akif! after upgrading the plugin now. 

I can see blank screen on run

 Error Log : D/skia (10371): Shader compilation error D/skia (10371): ------------------------ D/skia (10371): Errors: D/skia (10371): E/flutter (10371): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences) E/flutter (10371): D/skia (10371): Shader compilation erro –

Answer (score 0):

You can try to upgrade your [flutter_paystack package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_paystack). Now it has a new release(v1.0.4+1).

Comment: Thank you Akif!  after upgrading the plugin now. I can see blank screen on run Error Log : D/skia    (10371): Shader compilation error
D/skia    (10371): ------------------------
D/skia    (10371): Errors:
D/skia    (10371): 
E/flutter (10371): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
E/flutter (10371): 
D/skia    (10371): Shader compilation erro

Comment: You need to uninstall and then install your application again for this error: No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55726828/10659482

Comment: Thank you for your response... it didn't help .. same error

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me

In your MethodCallHandlerImpl.kt file, replace this:

```
        "getUserAgent" -> {
            result.success("Android_" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + "_Paystack_" + 
            BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
        }

        "getVersionCode" -> {
            result.success(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE.toString())
        }
```

with this:

```
       "getUserAgent" -> {
        //result.success("Android_" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + "_Paystack_" + 
         BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME)
        result.success("Android_" + "29" + "_Paystack_" + "1.0.0" )
       }
       "getVersionCode" -> {
        //result.success(BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE.toString())
        result.success("1")
       }
```

Thank me later. Happy Coding!