# shared preferences not working in the background in flutter

Tags: flutter, background-service

i am using  shared_preferences: ^2.0.7 with flutter_background_service: ^0.1.5 in flutter
but when call shared preferences give me the error

"Flutter: Unhandled exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)"

When working in the forground mode, the call is done correctly, this problem occurs only about the call in the background mode.

Comment: [flutter-unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687801/flutter-unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for)

Answer (score 5):

same issue's happend with me

in Background : it stores the value (checked by reading value after setting it)

in Foreground : it couldn't find any stored values

**Solution**

just reload the preference instance before Get & Set

```
 final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 prefs.reload();  // The magic line
```

Answer (score 1):

usually this happens when thirdparty pulgin files are not properly included in build apk , to avoid this try :

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
```

this will make sure proper build with required files.

Tip : when adding a new plugin to pubspec.yaml file avoid **Hot reload** and **Hot restart** make sure to build apk from scratch so that all required files included in your build.