# Shared preferences in flutter - error after flutter clear

Tags: flutter

i try to use shared preferences in flutter but i get this error and i tried to run flutter clear and still getting the same error

the error

> ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Test MissingPluginException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44357053/flutter-test-missingpluginexception)

Answer (score 2):

Have you add the `SharedPreferences` dependecies in `pubspec.yaml`.If not here's how you do it:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
```

From the error message I believe `SharedPreferences` don't have getAll method. Here's some example how you read data from `SharedPreferences` :

```
getStringValuesSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //Return String
  String stringValue = prefs.getString('stringValue');
  return stringValue;
}
getBoolValuesSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //Return bool
  bool boolValue = prefs.getBool('boolValue');
  return boolValue;
}
getIntValuesSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //Return int
  int intValue = prefs.getInt('intValue');
  return intValue;
}
getDoubleValuesSF() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //Return double
  double doubleValue = prefs.getDouble('doubleValue');
  return doubleValue;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. Can you show him an example of how to add it to pubspec.yaml?

Comment: @AldyYuan  
thanks but i have done all of this and still getting the same message error

Comment: Can you share your code where you use the SharePreferences

Comment: final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      prefs.setString('token', responseData['idToken']);

      prefs.setBool('logged', true);
      prefs.setString('userEmail', email);

Comment: its just like this and i use it when i log in but it does not work and gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

After you adding a new package. You have to run

```
flutter pub get
```

Then **rebuild** you app.

Answer (score 0):

for my case add setMockInitialValues({}) before sharedPreference.getInstance worked for me

```
SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await sharedPreferences.setString(key, value);
```